# OAuth connection not completed in Outlook Desktop Office 365 Addin

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

we are developing an office.js add-in that connects to CRM through OAuth.

Here is the oAuth flow:

1. User clicks connect to CRM, a new window opens
2. User connects to CRM and gets redirected to our Website
3. we will finish the OAUth process and send the token to parent document (Add-in)

   it is working fine in OWA but in Outlook Desktop we are unable to send the token to Parent document.

we tried:

1. local storage(parent window (add-in) watches local storage, once the token is received child window saves it in local storage but the parent is not receiving the local storage update until outlook is restarted)
2. customs events(didn't work due to IE same origin policy)

is this a bug in outlook? is there any other way we can pass the token to parent window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For authentication we recommend opening the auth window using the [displayDialogAsync API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins).

Then, the **Office.context.ui.messageParent** API can be called from the opened window to send a message pack to its parent.

Comment: this is working but slow, user already goes through multiple screens to complete OAuth process and then have to wait to load Office.js again and run initialize or  onReady and then pass the message to the parent. messy but works for now

Comment: @Add-ins Team: could you look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226711/how-to-implement-oauth-connection-to-3rd-party-from-outlook-mobile-app-addin