# how to implement OAuth connection to 3rd party from Outlook Mobile App addin

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

we tried opening a window,  office dialogAsyncApi but they didnt work. the call never returned to the add-in running in outlook mobile app on both android & ios. what is the preferred approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are some resources on using the dialog API in Office.js. They should be supported in Outlook Mobile on iOS and Android. This is preferrable to `window.open`.

[Dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins)

[Dialog API doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=office-js#displaydialogasync-startaddress--options--callback-)